# Elegant way of adding an CTA to a menu

Tags: menus

I'm new to WP and looking to put a Call To Action (CTA) to my main menu. Currently the *ordinary* items are left aligned, and the CTA would be right aligned. So far this is what I've thought:

- Hardcode it into the theme with the link to the page. Easy but ugly and error prone + the editor/author can't edit the link.
- Define a secondary menu and just get first item (`wp_get_nav_menu_items`?). Better but seems odd to use a menu just to get an element.

Any other idea? Is there a **prefered** way of doing this? I'm inclined for the second option but just wanted to know if there are more ways.

---

**Edit**: originally posted on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139247/elegant-way-of-adding-an-cta-to-a-menu-in-wordpress), Oliver's answer added down here. I repost the question because I think it better belongs here + I want more feedback.

Comment: CTA ? Computed tomography angiography ? Central Tibetan Administration ?

Comment: CTA is **Call To Action** i suppose.

Comment: **@doup** you have already ask this in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139247/elegant-way-of-adding-an-cta-to-a-menu-in-wordpress) and you have there the good answer of **Oliver White**:

You have to use the last item of your menu and set a custom class to it.

Then you will assign the necessary css rules to this class in main css file of your theme (or better child-theme) for example `float:right;` …

Comment: Updated original question. So, @Louis you also think that's **the good** answer? The user must be aware of the convention and remember to add the class? Feel free to add answers so that they can be voted & accepted.

Comment: You mean the Author/Editor user could delete this CTA menu item to replace it by a new one? In that case the user have to set the class in the new item menu. But if this user just edit this CTA menu item, there is no problem.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is another way, because in one of my client website i use **Menu Social Icons** free plugin, that can optional add social icons (CTA like) at the end of main menu. So if you look to the code of this plugin, you can find a lot of useful tricks to do what you are expecting: To have a CTA item in the right manageable from the back office with his own settings. But it is a real development.

Answer (score 0):

As posted in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139247/elegant-way-of-adding-an-cta-to-a-menu-in-wordpress) by [Oliver White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5223098/oliver-white):

> You can add this item as last in your menu, then assign custom class to this item and add required styles (positioning, CTA styles).